# Adding fields to an InfoPath form for a SharePoint content type

Tags: infopath, 2007

Can I add fields to an infopath form used as a SharePoint content type w/out losing my existing data for previously completed forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add fields to the infopath form and put them into play. Your existing forms will upgrade as long as you don't delete any currently existing fields. I have used this method myself to add to a form as requirements changed. When you publish the form, it will upgrade the forms currently in use either through the site collection or at a farm level if published through Central Administration